# how to call jscript onFormSubmit() with eventArgs e (classic asp)

Tags: asp-classic, javascript

If I have the following jscript code on a classic asp page, how do I supply the "eventArgs e" in the call so it will be available here in the jscript?  The "eventArgs e" being an asp.net term, I am not sure what is used here.

```
response.write "<script type='text/javascript'>"
response.write "function onFormSubmit(e)"
response.write "{ var keycode;"
response.write "if(window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;"
response.write "else if (e) keycode = e.which;"
response.write "else return true;"
response.write "if (keycode == 13)"
response.write "{ myform.submit();"
response.write "return false; }"
response.write "else return true; }"
response.write " </script>"
```

And the call looks like this:

```
response.write "<form name='myform' action='logon' method='post' onSubmit='onFormSubmit()'>"
```

Thank you,
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: let's go full solution. Does this work for you?

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function submitIfEnter(e)
      {
      var keycode;
      if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
      else if (e) keycode = e.which;
      else return true;

      if (keycode == 13)
         {
         var f = document.myform;
         f.action.value = "Forum Logon";
         f.submit();
         }
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

  <% 
  if request.form("action") <> "" then 
     response.write "submit value = " + request.form("bsubmit") + "<br />"
     response.write "action value = " + request.form("action") + "<br />"
  else
  %>
  <form method="post" name="myform">
    <input type="text" onkeydown="submitIfEnter(event);"/>
    <input type='hidden' name='action' value='action1'>
    <input type='submit' name='bsubmit' value='Guest Register'>
    <input type='submit' name='bsubmit' value='Forum Logon'>
  </form>
  <% 
  end if
  %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, but I think this is submitting the form, not the button I want. The problem was not getting the form to submit on enter.  I have two buttons, both with the same name but different values to I can tell on the code page which button was pressed.  But the wrong button is triggered on enter due to it's placement on the page.

Comment: Edited answer to explain better

Comment: Ok that looks a little different than what I was doing.  Thank you for the detail.  I am really new to asp classic.  Have only been working asp.net for one year.  The asp has given me plenty of challenges.  I will try this and advise of results.

Thanks,
Jim